# Bessel function of first kind

Tags: homework-and-exercises, integration, mathematics

Can someone tell me how

$$\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T e^{i(m-n)\omega t} e^{-ix\sin(\omega t)} e^{iy\sin(\omega t +\phi)}\, dt = J_{m-n}\left(\sqrt{x^2 +y^2 -2xy\cos(\phi)}\right)?$$

Comment: This is better suited for [math.se]

Comment: Migration rejected. OP apparently has a q ban on math.SE.

Answer (score 2):

First use  a phasor diagram to combine the two exponential bits
$$
x \sin \omega t +y \sin (\omega t+\phi)  = \sqrt{x^2+y^2-2xy \cos\phi} \sin (\omega t +\chi)
$$
where $\chi$ is some irrelevent angle. Then use the integral definition of $J_n(X)$